# Parse JSON with jQuery [2]

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to alert id and subcategory in JSON string returned from the server using jQuery.

I get the following JSON string.

```
[{"name":"Technology","id":117,"subcategory":"Machines"},
{"name":"Technology","id":118,"subcategory":"Tools"},
{"name":"Technology","id":119,"subcategory":"Air"}]
```

I try to do:

```
$.getJSON("scene/getSubCategories/Technology",
    {
        format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $.each(data.object, function(i,object){
            alert(object.id + " " +object.subcategory);
        });
    });
```

I'm getting the error

> Message: 'length' is null or not an object
>
> Line: 12
>
> Char: 7740
>
> Code: 0
>
> URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2, because I have a third-party JavaScript plugin which works with this jQuery version, and I can't figure how both (1.3.2 and 1.4.3) versions of jQuery can live together on the same side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){
    alert(item.id + " " +item.subcategory);
});
```

The first argument of `each()` has to be the object to iterate over. It has to be data (data has no property "object"). The second argument of the provided function will be the current item of the iterated object.

Answer (score 1):

"'length' is null or not an object" because `data.object` does not exist. You probably meant to type:

```
$.each(data, function(i,object) {
```

instead of

```
$.each(data.object, function(i,object) {
```

As a side note, in your case, you can use a native JavaScript for loop instead of $.each:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var object = data[i];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to getJSON() should be the function getting you parsed data.
each() gets an array and passes, in your case, index and value of an element

```
$.getJSON("scene/getSubCategories/Technology", function(data) {
     alert(data);
     $.each(data, function(i, object){
          alert(object.id + " " +object.subcategory);
     });
});
```